# How to minimize User Agent css code, It's unnecessarily increasing my css file size. can we write common code for all user agent?

Tags: html, css

How to minimize User Agent CSS code, It unnecessarily increasing my CSS file size. Can we write common code for all user agent?
Repetitive user agent code:

[image: Repetitive user agent code]

Comment: These keyword are necessary for browser compatibility, instead you should minify your css files to reduce the file size. [https://cssminifier.com/](https://cssminifier.com/)

Comment: `-moz-`  and `-op-` prefixes are no longer neccessary, because it's really hard to find some people with old versions of firefox and Opera now uses Blink / WebKit. `-webkit-`  prefix still necessary due iOS system. You can save from -moz- and -o- prefixes removing them.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rohit said, you have to keep the keywords to make it compatible with browsers.

However you still can split you CSS files so a javascript function is going to detect what browser you are using and will redirect you to the right CSS file.

Code ( thank's to @Jonno_FTW )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appName;
if browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"IE.css\">");
}
else if browser == "Firefox" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"FF.css\">");
}
else {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"generic.css\">");
}
</script>
```

Then you still can minify every CSS file to make them even smaller.